# XML nodes not getting deleted properly

Tags: java, xml, dom

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>myobj__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

The XML follows the above structure. I need to delete the middle nodes of the  node. i.e. the  and  should only be deleted, no matter how many times the program runs.
My attemps:

```
private static void removeNodes(Document document) {

    Node categories = document.getElementsByTagName("types").item(0);
    NodeList categorieslist = categories.getChildNodes();
    if(categorieslist != null) {
        while (categorieslist.getLength() > 1) {
            Node node = categorieslist.item(0);
            node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I run this program once its working fine, but when I run it twice thrice or more, the result is that it deletes the  node too, sometime it deletes both start and end tag of  node, sometime it leaves the end tag.
`categorieslist.getLength() > 1` is mentioned for the problem shown above but still it fails sometimes.

Tried with `categorieslist.getLength() > 0` and the result is below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>38.0</version>
 </Package>
```

**Expected Result**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
     </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
 </Package>
```

**Second Try**

```
private static void removeNodes(Document document) {

    DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) document;
    Node a = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
    Element b = null;
    for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
        Element e = (Element) n;
        b = e;
        if ("members".equals(e.getTagName())) {
            a.removeChild(b);
        }

        if ("name".equals(e.getTagName())) {
            a.removeChild(b);
        }
    }
```

Throwing error : `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist. 
at remove method.`

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I saw`categorieslist.getLength() > 1` , shouldn't that be `categorieslist.getLength() > 0`?

Comment: Yep I even tried that, but it fails sometimes.

Comment: Are you trying to keep all but the last one? What do you mean by "fails sometimes"?

Comment: I have updated the question after trying with zero. This is not the result I was expecting. Please check now @Zimano

Comment: but why would you run the code twice and expect the same output? Also where is your serialization part of the code?

Comment: For serialization I have used `TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();` so no issues there. I also tried deleting node by name, but it throws error. Updated as `Second Attemp`

Comment: `but when I run it twice thrice or more, the result is that it deletes the node too, sometime it deletes both start and end tag of node, sometime it leaves the end tag` please elaborate on it. What do you mean by twice, thrice ? Are you trying to delete nodes that are not there ? First time they get deleted and your xml gets updated, second time there are no child nodes under `types`.